# Plotly: How to show only the clicked line?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, ggplotly, plotly-python

By default, Plotly hides the line on click on its label in the legend section. 
Is there a combination of `shift/ctrl/alt/` any other keys to make only the selected line appear and hide all the other lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `double click left mouse button`. If this sounds to easy / good to be true, just try it yourself with this snippet:

**Code:**

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Americas'")
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", color='country')
fig.show()
```

**Plot 1:**

[image]

Now, if you'd like to look at Haiti only, just hover over the legend, `double clik left mouse button`, and this is what you'll get:

[image]

Comment: While this works, I understand that the question was regarding clicking on the chart itself. Not via the legend.

Comment: nice... Any way to do this programmatically?  (E.g. to start with only the first selected...)

Comment: @ntg Example to initialize as the bottom graph from above: `for trace in fig['data']:` `if trace['name'] not in ['country=Haiti']:` `trace['visible'] = 'legendonly'`. 

With help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68501527/4368898)