# How to disable a line in plotly at start?

Tags: python, plotly, hide, show

I would like to show the lines but with some are disabled. So just like when I show it normally and then click on its name to unshow/disable the line.
I am using python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**visible** attribute of a **trace** as `"legendonly"` makes a line behave in way you describe

Below code generates a **figure** with 10 lines, then sets **visible** to `legendonly` for lines 3 to 10.  Clicking on legend makes them visible.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({f"line{i+1}":np.random.uniform(i,i+2,100) for i in range(10)})
px.line(df, x=df.index, y=df.columns).update_traces(visible="legendonly", selector=lambda t: not t.name in ["line1","line2"])
```

[image]